# How should I index database tables in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I am new to elastic search and wanting to copy my entire database into elastic for advanced searching and analytics. My question is, should i just create one app index and "types" for each table. In my case this would be: 
- http://elastichost/my-cool-app/my-table/id

The db is about 15G atm and growing quickly, so i am looking for recommendations on the best index/type structure to use for elastic so i will not need to change the whole setup shortly after i create the indexes etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to recommend a structure without a data sample ...

Since you are new, something important with elasticsearch is **mapping** , this is how your data will be indexed and can be searched, you change the mapping => your data must be reindexed.

So the best advice, is to versionize index: `my-data-v1` and use an alias `my-data` linked to it. So you can change mapping, create a new index, re-index all your data, then change the alias, without down time. About index type, since version 6.x, index can have a single type (so no more worries about ^^).

About the mapping itself, no magic rule, read documentation, test and test.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the first step would be to **denormalise your data**.

For example if you have a customer_master with customer details, product_master with product details, and an orders table with customer_id, product_id and order details, it would be a good idea to denormalise all of them into a single table and index this table in a single index in ES. This way you can search for orders by customer details, product details or order details.

You can then create one denormalised index for each set of related tables and index them in ES.

15 GB does not look like its a lot of data. (We have indexed 300 million rows of data in a small ES cluster based on 4 commodity hardware machines. Data size was in 100s of GB)

I would like to add that there is no perfect way to index data and you will have to experiment with multiple ideas before finalising one. If you are using ES as analytics platform (and not as a primary source of data) indexing data multiple times in the experiment phase should not be a problem.

My 2 cents.